# Get all form values into javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am attempting to get all the form values into a normal array[]. I had it working for  tags but then I added some  tags and can't seem to get it.

With just  tags it worked with this

```
var content = document.querySelectorAll("#form input[name='content[]']");
```

I am currently trying something like this

```
var content = document.elements["content[]"].value;
```

This form can change from user input down the road as each section of the form is a module that they choose to add. It is also important to get the values in order, if that isn't possible then I would need to make it a JSON array. Pure javascript or jquery is fine either way.

Thank you for any help.

**EDIT**

I used this to solve my problem

```
  var contents=[]
  var content = $('#form').serializeArray()
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    contents[contents.length]=content[i].value
  };
```

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at jQuery's serializeArray http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/

Comment: note that in JavaScripts, arrays can't have strings for keys, only numbers (you can force names in, and they will be completely ignored by the bits that make the array an actual array, like .length, .forEach(), etc). If you want a "dictionary" type object, you actually want a regular JavaScript object.

Comment: @kinakuta after looking into that it is exactly what I wanted. just extracted the values in order. Updated question with the answer I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

html

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="content[]" value="abc" />
    <textarea name="textarea" value="">123</textarea>
</form>
```

js

```
$(function() {
  var form = $("#form");
    // escape `[]`
    var content = form.find("input[name=content\\[\\]]");
    // array `literal declaration` 
    var _arr = [content.prop("value")];
    // map all form values to single array
    var arr = $.map(form.serializeArray(), function(v, k) {
      return [v.value]
    });
    // array literal with `textarea` `value`
    var t = [$("textarea").prop("value")];
    console.log(_arr, arr, t); 
    // _arr: `["abc"]` , arr:`["abc", "123"]` t:`["123"]` 
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/785hgz4L/).

See [Arrays](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/arrays/)

Comment: A short description would be suitable along with the answer.

Comment: Does this find <textarea> content also? I updated the OP with a solution.

Comment: @sdla4ever Didn't try `textarea` , though `var _arr = [content.prop("value")];` should return same for `textarea` . Issue may have been escaping of `[]` within `name` ? Thanks